# Working with Google Maps Android - Read CSV File Issue

Tags: java, android, google-maps

So I am writing an activity based on this google Maps example:

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/tutorials/MapWithMarker/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapwithmarker/MapsMarkerActivity.java

I have api credentials, have configured and successfully displaying a static map pin from within the map using this code:

```
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng test = new LatLng(0, 45.505);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(test)
                .title("Test Marker"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(test));
}
```

I have another activity that appends to a csv file located at /storage/emulated/0/csvLogs/source.csv in the following format:

date,title,lat,long

Below I am trying to write code to call multiple tokens per line in the format necessary from a csv file. I am looking for the final outcome to display a map pin / title for every line in the csv file. Not looking to load the csv from assets either. I think I am close, will someone please correct this code + add any imports i may need. Thank you very much.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.String;




public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    GoogleMap map;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }




    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        File fileGet = new File("/storage/emulated/0/csvLogs/source.csv");
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileGet));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
                String[] token = line.split(",");
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(token[2]);
                double lon = Double.parseDouble(token[3]);
                LatLng Lat = new LatLng(lat, lon);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Lat).title(token[1]));
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Lat));
            }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

There is currently 0 errors but does not open activity without crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final working code, Got this working this morning and have been testing.

Zag is correct about malformed csv files. Make sure you are sanitizing and encoding plain text data because commas , within your plain text data will interfere with parsing the csv file correctly!

````
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        File fileGet = new File("/storage/emulated/0/csvLogs/demo.csv");
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileGet));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
                String[] token = line.split(",");
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(token[2]);
                double lon = Double.parseDouble(token[3]);
                LatLng Lat = new LatLng(lat, lon);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Lat).title(token[1]));
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Lat));
            }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

```
````

Answer (score 1):

Does this even compile?  This line puzzles me:

```
LatLng Lat = new LatLng(s2=token[2].getText().toString() + "," + s3=token[3].getText().toString());
```

token is an array of Strings, so simply token[2] is going to give you a String.  String doesn't have a getText() method, to my knowledge, and I'm not sure where the s2 and s3 variables are defined, nor why you're assigning to them in the middle of the string expression.

Assuming LatLng has a constructor that takes such a String, then just the following should do it.

```
LatLng Lat = new LatLng(token[2] + "," + token[3]);
```

However, you're seriously trusting your CSV file to be well-formed, which I never would.  At the very least, throw in a line like

```
if (token.length >= 4) {
```

and surround your next three lines with the curly braces, so you don't try to process empty lines in your file.

You also might want to use a CSV reader library, which handles makes your CSV reading much cleaner and more reliable.